# Error icono corrido span html

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema , de que forma puedo colocar un icono en el span que contiene "$", al colocar el icono de la plantilla este queda corrido , el icono debería quedar en el lugar del "$" y no encima del nombre combustible muchas gracias saludos,

```
<section class="col col-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="icon-append fa fa-user"></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre Combustible</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar lo sugerido el icono se sobrepone

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/812939c945.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="col col-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="icon-append fa fa-user"></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre Combustible</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: codigo necesitamos codigo para ayudarte

Comment: Amigo, copia tu código y pégalo en tu pregunta. Si las imágenes se caen, ¿cómo futuros visitantes podrán ver el código?

Answer (score 1):

Agrega la clase input-group-addon al addon que necesitas

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to thenearest dollar)">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>
```

de esta forma bootstrap detecta que quieres ponerlo al principio del input.

Comment: según lo sugerido , el icono efectivamente cambio de lugar , pero queda sobrepuesto gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo así, sin olvidar la clase `input-group-addon` en el `<span>` que contiene el símbolo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/812939c945.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="col col-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon fa fa-user"></span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre Combustible</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Esta es otra opción agregando un nuevo elemento para contener el icono, pero debo insistir en que no sería necesario hacerlo ya que el selector `:before` de `fa-user` agrega el icono en UTF-8 antes del contenido:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/812939c945.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="col col-6">
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><b class="fa fa-user"></b></span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre Combustible</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: me sigue sucediendo lo mismo , por lo que veo , creo que se debe a un choque de css, los css de la plantilla se sobreponen en las clases de bootstrap , alguna forma de conseguir mover el icono a nivel de css?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo exacto de tu problema no podré reproducirlo y arreglarlo. Con el ejemplo que te he modificado el problema se soluciona, si persiste tendrás que modificarlo hasta que sea igual que el que te produce el erro problema.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, era necesario usar una etiqueta "i"con el nombre de la clase del icono gracias

```
<section class="col col-6">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre Combustible</span>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Realmente no es necesario usar una etiqueta `<i>`, si no que cualquier tipo de etiqueta te hubiera valido (por ejemplo `<b>`, `<span>`, `<u>`, etc). ¿Qué navegador usas? Es raro porque los efectos deberían ser los mismos ya que lo único que hace font awesome es agregar códigos UTF-8 con el símbolo (`content: "\f007"` en tu caso) en el selector `:before` (agrega texto ANTES del contenido). ¿La clase `icon-append` para qué la necesitabas?